# Simple mysql join not working right

Tags: mysql, join

I have

```
SELECT country.* , COUNT( country.coid ) AS city_count_for_country
FROM `air_countries` AS country
JOIN `air_cities` AS city ON city.coid = country.coid
```

but it returns just one country and city_count_for_country doesn't count all cities for one country but just all cities. Whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is only achievable by the `group by` keyword; `JOIN` alone never aggregates rows; You probably want to write

```
SELECT country.* , COUNT( country.coid ) AS city_count_for_country
   FROM air_countries AS country
   JOIN air_cities AS city
   ON city.coid = country.coid
   GROUP BY country.coid
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group it

```
SELECT country.* , COUNT( country.coid ) AS city_count_for_country
FROM `air_countries` AS country
JOIN `air_cities` AS city ON city.coid = country.coid
GROUP BY country.coid
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `GROUP BY` clause.  Try this:

```
select country.coid, count(*) as city_count_for_country
from `air_countries` as country
join `air_cities` as city on city.coid = country.coid
group by country.coid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the group function, by adding to your query

```
GROUP BY country.coid
```